# How to convert from UTC to local time in R?

Tags: r

I have 24 values that were taken as hourly measurements `(a00 to a23)` in `UTC (universal time)` for one day for a region with a `longitude of 30o`.  I simply want to know which one of these 24 values correspond to `1:00 am` local time. Is this possible using R?

```
 a00=c(65);a01=c(45);a02=c(35);a03=c(25);a04=c(95);a05=c(65);a06=c(35);a07=c(25);a08=c(65);a09=c(45);a10=c(95);a11=c(85);a12=c(75);a13=c(95);a14=c(55);a15=c(35);a16=c(15);a17=c(58);a18=c(56);a19=c(54);a20=c(53);a21=c(55);a22=c(35);a23=c(15)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`POSIXct` automatically uses your local time

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.POSIXlt.html

```
# ways to convert this
as.POSIXct(z, origin = "1960-01-01")                # local
as.POSIXct(z, origin = "1960-01-01", tz = "GMT")    # in UTC
```